# Emacs ansi-term and term not working well when I ssh into a remote machine

Tags: ssh, terminal, emacs

I have the exact same Emacs configuration on a local and remote machine, and when I run `M-x ansi-term` or `M-x term` on each of them individually everything works great.

However, if I run any of these term emulators on Emacs on the local machine, and then I ssh into the remote machine, the prompt is not displayed correctly and my input doesn't work well either.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: Do you have the same Emacs versions? Same distributions? Same locale settings (`locale -a`)? What do you mean by “not display correctly” and “doesn't work well”: describe precisely what you see and how it differs.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `TERM` environment variable should be the same on both systems.